# Error regarding it exceeds the max of "500KB" Babel

Tags: babeljs, babel-loader

This issue was one I never had but it just randomly started after completing my game over a month now.

Whenever I run

```
npm run webpack --watch ./lib/saviors.js bundle.js
```

I keep getting

```
[BABEL] Note: The code generator has deoptimised the styling of "/Users/steven/Desktop/Saviors/bundle.js" as it exceeds the max of "500KB".
```

and my bundle.js.map continue to increase in size. Can someone tell me the reason for this? I'm confused as it just started randomly. While looking online I noticed people mentioned we needed to have /node_modules/ which I already have. Anyone else found a different solution to this problem?

```
module: {
loaders: [
  {
    test: [/\.jsx?$/, /\.js?$/],
    exclude: /node_modules/,
    loader: 'babel-loader',
    query: {
      presets: ['es2015']
    }
  }
]
},
```

Thank you to those who help and provide some advice.

Comment: Why are you passing filenames as arguments to `webpack`? All that should be defined inside your `webpack.config.js` file.

Comment: @loganfsmyth WOW Thank you. I don't know how I was missing that one. If you can write it as a solution I would give you the credit since you were right about that one. Really thank you and sorry for making such a easy minor mistake like that one.

Comment: In my case that happened after I accidentaly added not necessary browser-sync modules to my nativescript project. The solution is to remove these packages or reverse your git repo to properly working version.